# how to get object of a nested child

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
[
    {
        "childKey": "o4oqRIVA3bdY33",
        "childData": {
            "serviceCity": "Santa Rosa",
            "serviceDate": {
                "2018-01-31": {
                    "clientId": "Y8valE4BUynL3y",
                    "Booked": false,
                    "shift": "Night"
                },
                "2018-02-02": {
                    "clientId": "Y8va12asdynL3y",
                    "Booked": false,
                    "shift": "Night"
                }
            },
            "serviceProvince": "Laguna"
        }
    }
]
```

this is what my current response is..
i have a variable that holds a data that is being pass by ajax.
`var startDate = '2018-01-31'`
what i wanted to do is to get the this response if `serviceDate` matches/has the same `startDate`

```
router.get('/newWatch/:uuid',function(req, res){
    var avail = database.ref('availableWatch');
    var startDate = req.params.uuid;

    avail.once('value', function(snapshot){
        var promises = [];

        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
            var childData = childSnapshot.val().serviceDate;
            var Datestarts = childData[startDate];
            console.log(Datestarts);
        }); 

        res.json(promises)
    });
});
```

but the problem i can get the whole data but not the data from serviceDate specifically. i dont know it using forEach is the right thing to do.. what im trying to do is to get the availableWatch which have a `serviceDate of 2018-01-31..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
router.get('/newWatch/:uuid',function(req, res){
    var avail = database.ref('availableWatch');
    var startDate = req.params.uuid;

    avail.once('value', function(snapshot){
        var promises = [];

        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
             promises.push(childSnapshot.childData.serviceDate[startDate]);
        });

        res.json(promises)
    });
});
```

Comment: just an add up..from this how to get the shift if day or night?

Comment: `snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
    if(childSnapshot.childData.serviceDate[startDate].shift === "Night")
        promises.push(childSnapshot.childData.serviceDate[startDate]);
});`

Answer (score 0):

You missed this : `childSnapshot.childData.serviceDate`.

This should work for you :

```
snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
            var childData = childSnapshot.childData.serviceDate;
            var Datestarts = childData[startDate];
            console.log(Datestarts);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

As i understood from your question that you want to execute AJAX only if startDate matches one of the dates in serviceDate.

You can use `Object.keys()` to fetch keys of serviceDate from the response and code proceed accordingly.

```
var response=[
    {
        "childKey": "o4oqRIVA3bdY33",
        "childData": {
            "serviceCity": "Santa Rosa",
            "serviceDate": {
                "2018-01-31": {
                    "clientId": "Y8valE4BUynL3y",
                    "Booked": false,
                    "shift": "Night"
                },
                "2018-02-02": {
                    "clientId": "Y8va12asdynL3y",
                    "Booked": false,
                    "shift": "Night"
                }
            },
            "serviceProvince": "Laguna"
        }
    }
]
```

then

var serviceDateData=Object.keys(response[0].childData.serviceDate);

`serviceDateData` will contain `["2018-01-31", "2018-02-02"]`

Now you can use your logic to implement the required functionality.
Hope it helps you